# Could a solar panel be modified to also collect a static charge on Mars?

Tags: mars, engine-design, rovers, solar-power, design-alternative

I was waiting for someone to piece both of these questions together into another question. @Dragongeek was the first, Could a solar panel be modified to create a static charge while spinning to remove dust during a dust storm?

This question asks how dust could be removed from a panel through spinning it: [Fast spining solar cells to clear Martian dust possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/fast-spining-solar-cells-to-clear-martian-dust-possible)

This question asks how a static charge is made with spinning blades: [Could electricty be generated from a Martian dust storm?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35587/could-electricty-be-generated-from-a-martian-dust-storm)

How could the solar panel be modified for a dual purpose? 1) Normal solar function while there is no dust storm. 2) Bach up self-cleaning mode while spinning to create a static charge from the dust storm.

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/113020/can-static-electricity-damage-solar-cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to *avoid* building up a static charge.  Static charges tend to be very high-voltage but low-energy, meaning they're good for destroying machinery, but not good for powering it.

It's quite easy to modify a solar panel to collect a static charge: just isolate it from the spacecraft's grounding system.  But once you do that, you'll need to deal with miniature lightning bolts seeking a path to ground, and the shortest path probably goes through the electronics the solar panels normally power.  Not a good thing.

Comment: Could be used to collect that before it builds up too high? Without interfering with normal functions? Wind turbine solar cell static charge collector?